# For a Silverlight 4 Visual Studio solution, what needs to be in version control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, version-control

I have a Silverlight 4 app that I'm building with Visual Studio 2010. I'm using Mercurial/TortoiseHG to do version control. Which files do I need to check in? By default, it checks in all sorts of .dlls in /bin/debug and stuff. Do I really need those? Or can I just grab code and content files? Do I need to version something to keep track of project properties and references, or is that contained within the .csproj file itself?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to include stuff in /bin or /obj.  This is true of all VS solutions in source control.  These are recreated upon every rebuild.  Also, for Silverlight specifically, you don't need to check in the XAP file that is generated in the ClientBin of your web app.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms171339.aspx) (via [this social.msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/a0f12f42-3238-4db3-be4b-c233b0813c4b/)):

> You can add the following files to Visual Studio source control:
>
> - Solution files (*.sln).
> - Project files, for example, *.csproj, *.vbproj files.
> - Application configuration files, based on XML, used to control run-time behavior of a Visual Studio project.
>
> Files that you cannot add to source control include the following:
>
> - Solution user option files (*.suo).
> - Project user option files, for example, *.csproj.user, *.vbproj.user files.
> - Web information files, for example, *.csproj.webinfo, *.vbproj.webinfo, that control the virtual root location of a Web project.
> - Build output files, for example, *.dll and *.exe files.

It doesn't say anything specific about Silverlight projects though.

Comment: You can check in .suo files if you want to share settings like unloaded projects, breakpoints, etc. Also, if for example you are using a shared resource project you might want to import that as .dll in your XAP production project if you want to keep it versioned (other option is to import it as project and it will be built every time you build your main project)

Answer (score 0):

Is Mercurial/TortoiseHG integrated into Visual Studio? i.e. can you check out/submit from within VS?

If so, if you right click on the project name and select "Add Solution to Source Control" it should add those parts of the project that it needs ignoring everything else.